# What means "x=sorted(list(set(x for name,x in marksheet)))" in this python code?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

```
marksheet=[]
marksheet = [[input(), float(input())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
        

x=sorted(list(set(x for name,x in marksheet)))
print(x)
```

I've just started studying python,I'm not understand the "set(x for name,x in marksheet)" part.What is mean of that ?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: `marksheet` is a list of `[name, x]` pairs.  The `set` being built is just the `x`s; since it's a `set` it only has one of each unique value.

Comment: What the code is doing overall is prompting for a number, and then prompting for a pair of values that many times.  It discards the first value of each pair, and prints a sorted and deduplicated list of the second values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
x = set(x for name,x in marksheet)
```

First, the `x` on the right has nothing to do with the `x` on the left. I'll call the one on the right `x_i` to distinguish them.

1. `set`: We're going to make a Python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). A `set` is a container (like a list) with the rule that each item may only appear once.
2. `x_i for name,x_i in marksheet`: This is a generator expression (like a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)). It's a shortcut for doing a `for` loop.
3. `name,x_i in marksheet`: This is [tuple unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/). `marksheet` looks something like `[(name1, x1), (name2, x2), ...]`: it is a list of lists. The `name,x_i` there could also be written `(name, x_i)`: more explicitly a tuple.

The same code could be written:

```py
x = set([])  # start with an empty set
for name, x_i in marksheet:
    x.add(x_i)
```

So it selects the unique values of the second element of each pair in `marksheet`.

Since `name` isn't used, it's common to use the dummy variable `_` for that. You could use a direct set comprehension, too, instead of a generator expression:

```py
x = {x_i for _, x_i in marksheet}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set is a data structure that ensures that only one copy of each item inside it exists. So only copy of a person's name and its corresponding marks can exist.

So if marksheet is like

```py
[97.5, 45.3, 97.5]
```

Then applying the set operation will convert it to

```py
[97.5, 45.3]
```

Comment: The set is constructed from the second value of the inner list only. Otherwise a simple `set(marksheet)` would have been enough.

Comment: Yeah, the confusing formatting threw me off until I realised lists cant be hashed.